# How to calculate the mass moment of inertia of an elliptical ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, integration, moment-of-inertia

While I was trying to find out the mass moment of inertia of an elliptical ring I got struck and could not think about as to what I must do. I tried integrating but the radius keeps changing from semi major to semi minor. I have also tried using the perpendicular axis theorem but again the maths is starting to go over my head. and despite all of this I haven't come any closer to anything that remotely looks like a solution to my problem.

I am also unable to guess as for what kind of piece of the ellipse shaped ring I should take so as to integrate them to find out the moment of inertia

Comment: Keep working at it. It won't help you for us to do it for you. And about which axis are you trying to calculate it?

Comment: Interesting question. Please show your work. For some shapes the integral will be difficult.

Comment: Probably not that difficult actually. You can work it out from the [area moment of inertia for an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_second_moments_of_area) by differentiating wrt $a$ and $b$, or subtracting MI for ellipse with axes $(a,b)$ from one with axes $(a+\delta a, b+(b/a)\delta a)$.